# MySQL complex query. Server is suspended after executing query

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

GIVEN: big DB (`15GB`). Millions of rows across 10 tables.
TASK: To retrieve info from 3 tables (`table_a, table_b, table_c`). 
Tables are connected through

```
Foreign_Keys table_c<-table_b->table_a
(table_b has foreign keys for other tables)
```

`table_b` has multiple sequences(parts) for each row in table_a.
`Table_c` has names for each sequence in `table_b`.
Result should be:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  table_a.id   | table_c.firstsequence  |  table_c.LASTsequence    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My QUERY is

```
SELECT 
    a.id, c.sequence_name, 
    (SELECT z.sequence_id FROM table_b as z WHERE z.a_fk_id = a.id 
     order by z.sequence_order desc limit 1) as last_sequence
FROM table_a AS a
JOIN table_b AS b ON a.id = b.a_fk_id 
JOIN table_c AS c ON c.id = b.s_fk_id 
WHERE 
b.sequence_order = 1
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

But the `mysql` server just stops. It is suspended. No errors.
Thanks for your thoughts.
PS. This is real query is only different by names of tables and columns.

Comment: I think your subquery can be replaced by a simple `MAX(b.sequence_id)`,just add a GROUP BY a.id.Table definitions would also help,sequence_order should be indexed

Comment: Suspended doesn't let us know what exactly happens. The daemon crashes? I suggest doing a `COUNT()` query first to see how many records there would be.

Comment: This may be complex enough to warrant a move to dba.stackexchange but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you share the db schema with some dummy data and actual result what you want

Comment: can't say 15 GB db size as bigdata, please share all 3 tables count, structure and have you enabled innodb_file_per_table=1 if using innodb engine.

Comment: @Mihai : Not in this case. every trip has multiple sequences. To simplify, I put here foreign key as a simple one, But in my real example it is composite.

Comment: Thanks all for answers. But I can not share tables. Sorry. I found another longer solution. But it works fine. It involves creating temp table and execute multiple queries.